# In 1 dimension, the curvature of Ψ = K.E. of wave. Is this the case for 2 dimensions and 3 dimensions also?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In 1 dimension, the curvature of Ψ = K.E. of wave. Is this the case for 2 dimensions and 3 dimensions also? Moreover, is curvature of Ψ = K.E. of wave = 2nd derivative of Ψ?

Comment: If you drop the usage of the word "curvature" altogether, the rest would be true.

Comment: I think "curvature" is still used in three dimensions, at least, I've seen it before when discussing KE + PE contributions to the energy...

Comment: Ivan Neretin slide 19 of this powerpoint, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_007S11_lec40.pdf, states clearly that curvature of wavefunction = K.E. of wave